# Reading/Parsing Snort Alert File Using Python

Tags: python, parsing, logging, alerts, snort

What is the best way of setting parts of a text file (snort alert) into separate variables?

e.g. "Snort Log Output"

```
08/17-11:41:07.350700  [**] [1:1000011:0] [*] [Priority: 0] {TCP} 192.168.0.1:24586 -> 192.168.0.8:53804
```

I need to set:

```
08/17-11:41:07.350700
192.168.0.1:24586
192.168.0.8:53804
```

to separate variables.

It is not essential, but I would like the possibility of reading/setting multiple alerts from the same file.

But first I would like to set only one alert.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parsing strings is often done using regular expressions. I recommend reading the [re module documentation](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/re.html).

But in your case you could get away with the `split()` string method:

```
>>> s='08/17-11:41:07.350700 [] [1:1000011:0] [] [Priority: 0] {TCP} 192.168.0.1:24586 -> 192.168.0.8:53804'
>>> rec = s.split()
>>> rec
['08/17-11:41:07.350700', '[]', '[1:1000011:0]', '[]', '[Priority:', '0]', '{TCP}', '192.168.0.1:24586', '->', '192.168.0.8:53804']
>>> ts = rec[0]
>>> src = rec[6]
>>> dst = rec[7]
```

Comment: Thank You for your input, very helpful. I will spend some time reading over regular expressions

Answer (score 1):

A variant on the theme.

```
#Python 2.7.3

snort = '08/17-11:41:07.350700 [**] [1:1000011:0] [*] [Priority: 0] {TCP} 192.168.0.1:24586 -> 192.168.0.8:53804'

(dt,x,x,x,x,x,x,ip1,x,ip2) = snort.split()

print (dt,ip1,ip2)
('08/17-11:41:07.350700', '192.168.0.1:24586', '192.168.0.8:53804')
```